# Google DialogFlow Confidence

Tags: speech-recognition, dialogflow-es, google-speech-api

I'm trying to utilize dialogflow to build automated phone systems(IVR). Below is a sample result from dialog flow. DialogFlow spits out two confidence scores  are two confidence scores speechRecognitionConfidence and intentDetectionConfidence.

What is the minimum threshold value for speechRecognitionConfidence? i.e. is there a value which we can definitely say the transcription is inaccurate? Is there a range above the min threshold which the results may be is inaccurate (in this scenario, i would like to confirm with the user if their input is valid). Also what exactly goes into calculating this score?

```
 {
      "responseId": "a282e405-bc99-4e32-8746-76c79713b30f",
      "queryResult": {
        "queryText": "Reserve something",
        "speechRecognitionConfidence": 0.91684866,
        "action": "input.bookFlights",
        "parameters": {
          "geo-country1": "",
          "date": "",
          "geo-country": "",
          "flight_type": ""
        },
        "fulfillmentText": "Please specify a date",
        "fulfillmentMessages": [
          {
            "text": {
              "text": [
                "Please specify a date"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "outputContexts": [
          {
            "name": "projects/tripplanner-94399/agent/sessions/73621660-efb6-4b44-a86f-c6088ed4cf6d/contexts/b8f55a17-3e62-4feb-9c0d-1ded08d98122_id_dialog_context",
            "lifespanCount": 2,
            "parameters": {
              "date.original": "",
              "geo-country1.original": "",
              "geo-country": "",
              "flight_type.original": "",
              "geo-country1": "",
              "date": "",
              "flight_type": "",
              "geo-country.original": ""
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/tripplanner-94399/agent/sessions/73621660-efb6-4b44-a86f-c6088ed4cf6d/contexts/blookflight_dialog_params_date",
            "lifespanCount": 1,
            "parameters": {
              "date.original": "",
              "geo-country1.original": "",
              "geo-country": "",
              "flight_type.original": "",
              "geo-country1": "",
              "date": "",
              "flight_type": "",
              "geo-country.original": ""
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/tripplanner-94399/agent/sessions/73621660-efb6-4b44-a86f-c6088ed4cf6d/contexts/blookflight_dialog_context",
            "lifespanCount": 2,
            "parameters": {
              "flight_type.original": "",
              "geo-country1": "",
              "date": "",
              "flight_type": "",
              "geo-country.original": "",
              "date.original": "",
              "geo-country1.original": "",
              "geo-country": ""
            }
          }
        ],
        "intent": {
          "name": "projects/tripplanner-94399/agent/intents/b8f55a17-3e62-4feb-9c0d-1ded08d98122",
          "displayName": "BlookFlight"
        },
        "intentDetectionConfidence": 0.48,
        "diagnosticInfo": {},
        "languageCode": "en"
      }
    }
```